# Extract digit from string and transfer into 2 decimal

Tags: java, string, int, double, decimal

i have a string object

```
String s = "64.5369474 British pounds"
```

what i want is to have a methos that can get the digits out and transfer into 2 decimal place, 
the result i expect to get is something like:

```
String result = "64.54 British pounds"
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00.00");
String unformatedMoney = "65.432784327489";
String formattedMoney = df.formart(unformattedMoney);
System.out.println(formattedMoney + " British pounds");
```

Comment: OP asked for a suggestion not for someone to write out his program for him/her. How is he/she going to learn?

Answer (score 3):

I'll guide you but will not show you a full solution. One way is to:

1. Split the String to extract the number - See [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).
2. Convert the first String (Here I assume that the format is fixed) using [Double#parseDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29).
3. Use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to truncate the number.
4. The result String can be easily reconstructed.